Jupyter and Spyder fail to launch after last ubuntu update
JUPYTER
After the last ubuntu (22.04) update, jupyter fails to launch with the following error:

Unable to open document
“file:///home/user1/.local/share/jupyter/runtime/jpserver-6731-open.html”.
File type HTML document (text/html) is not supported.

I activate the venv environment and type:  jupyter-lab, and then get the above error message.
The file exists and I can launch Jupyter using either of the url links contained in the file in a browser.
SPYDER
I activate the venv environment and type:  spyder, and then spyder shows its splash-screen, and crashes.  This is the error in the venv terminal:

TypeError: KernelComm._get_call_return_value() missing 1 required
positional argument: 'comm_id' Segmentation fault (core dumped)

These error occur in all the venv virtual pythoh environments on the machine.
Is there asystem setting to fix it/them?

I think I discovered the problem.  I am using KDE.  Something in the Ubuntu update switched the default application for html in KDE.   I solved it by going into the settings->applications.  There I switched the maps to something other than it was and pressed save.  Then I pressed the default button, and again pressed save.   Now it seems to work.   Hope this helps if you have the same problem.

After you reset the default KDE applications, jupyter should work.  But you may need to uninstall spyder and reinstall it to get around its error.
